# Subset daily time series data by month

Tags: r

How I can select all days time series of a month from the following data-frame:

```
time <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("1985-05-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), by = "day"))
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
Mays.Decs <- time[months(time(time), TRUE) %in% c("Dec", "May")]
```

Comment: `Mays.Decs <- time[months(time[,1], TRUE) %in% c("Dec", "May"),]`. Also, don't use `time` as the name of your data.frame. It is an `R` function and its use for a variable name could lead to confusions like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach involves including a name for the 'date' column, and using that column to subset, similarly to how you have in your question.

```
# Add variable name for date column
time <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1985-05-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), by = "day")) 

# Subset 
time[months(time$date) %in% c("December", "May"),]
```